# Keras writing a Recurrent Layer which accepts images

Tags: python, machine-learning, theano, keras

This question exists as an issue, too: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/4266

I'm trying to implement a Convolutional - LSTM. 
It's a recurrent layer which accepts an image as input and uses a convolution to calculate the various gates in the LSTM.
So I'm trying to subclass `Recurrent`and change the input dimension.

In order to do that I read the documentation on [writing a custom layer](https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/) and followed the suggestion to read source code to understand what's happening under the hood.

I read the code for recurrent.py and think that the structure is clear: You inherit from `Recurrent` but you don't overwrite call, instead you provide a custom `step`function and `Recurrent`will take care of applying the step to each entry in a sequence.

As a starting point I took the code for the GRU and tried to adapt it to my needs.
I want to combine a 2D convolution and a GRU (usually it's an LSTM, but that doesn't really matter - I decided to implement a C-GRU)

The idea is to have a usual 2D convolution in the model which outputs 3 features. Those 3 features will be used as the r,z and h activations in the GRU. In the custom layer I only have to keep track of the state. My layer doesn't even have trainable weights, they are contained in the convolution.

Notable changes to the original `GRU`code are:

```
def step(self, x, states):
    # the previous state is a 2D vector
    h_tm1 = states[0]  # previous memory

    z=self.inner_activation(x[:,0,:,:])
    r=self.inner_activation(x[:,1,:,:])
    hh=self.activation(x[:,2,:,:])

    h = z * h_tm1 + (1 - z) * hh
    return h, [h]
```

As you can see, I'm simply reusing the features from the convolution. The multiplications should be performed element-wise. I'll debug this to make sure it has the intended behaviour.

Since the state becomes 2D, I'm changing the `initial_state`, too:

```
def get_initial_states(self, x):
    initial_state=K.zeros_like(x)   # (samples, timesteps, input_dim)
                                    # input_dim = (3, x_dim, y_dim)
    initial_state=K.sum(initial_state, axis=(1,2)) # (samples, x_dim, y_dim)
    return initial_state
```

The `output_shape` seems to be hardcoded for Recurrent networks. I'm overriding it:

```
def get_output_shape_for(self, input_shape):
    #TODO: this is hardcoding for th layout
    return (input_shape[0],1,input_shape[2],input_shape[3])
```

Another thing that's hardcoded is the `input_spec`.
In the constructor, after the call to super, I'm overriding it with my input dimension:

```
class CGRU(Recurrent):
    def __init__(self,
                 init='glorot_uniform', inner_init='orthogonal',
                 activation='tanh', inner_activation='hard_sigmoid', **kwargs):

        self.init = initializations.get(init)
        self.inner_init = initializations.get(inner_init)
        self.activation = activations.get(activation)
        self.inner_activation = activations.get(inner_activation)

        #removing the regularizers and the dropout

        super(CGRU, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        # this seems necessary in order to accept 5 input dimensions
        # (samples, timesteps, features, x, y)
        self.input_spec=[InputSpec(ndim=5)]
```

There are other small changes.
You can find the whole code here: http://pastebin.com/60ztPis3

When ran, this produces the following error message:

> theano.tensor.var.AsTensorError: ('Cannot convert [None] to TensorType', )

The whole error message on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/Cdmr20Yn

I'm trying to debug the code. But that's rather hard, it goes deep into the Keras source code.
One thing: The execution never reaches my custom `step`function. So apparently something in the configuration is going wrong. In the `call`function of `Recurrent`, input_shape is a tuple with the entries `(None, 40,1,40,40)`

This is correct. My sequence has 40 elements. Each one is an image with 1 feature and 40x40 resolution. I'm using the "th" layout.

Here is the `call` function of `Recurrent`.
My code reaches the call to `K.rnn`, the setup looks fine to me. Input_spec seems correct.
But during `K.rnn` it crashes. Without reaching my step function.

```
def call(self, x, mask=None):
    # input shape: (nb_samples, time (padded with zeros), input_dim)
    # note that the .build() method of subclasses MUST define
    # self.input_spec with a complete input shape.
    input_shape = self.input_spec[0].shape
    if self.stateful:
        initial_states = self.states
    else:
        initial_states = self.get_initial_states(x)
    constants = self.get_constants(x)
    preprocessed_input = self.preprocess_input(x)

    last_output, outputs, states = K.rnn(self.step, preprocessed_input,
                                         initial_states,
                                         go_backwards=self.go_backwards,
                                         mask=mask,
                                         constants=constants,
                                         unroll=self.unroll,
                                         input_length=input_shape[1])
```

At this point I'm lost.
It seems to me that I'm missing some part of the configuration.

**UPDATE:**

Hm, now I'm having a strange problem:
My code is now:

```
# this is the actual input, fed to the network
inputs = Input((1, 40, 40, 40))

# now reshape to a sequence
reshaped = Reshape((40, 1, 40, 40))(inputs)

conv_inputs = Input((1, 40, 40))
conv1 = Convolution2D(3, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(conv_inputs)
convmodel = Model(input=conv_inputs, output=conv1)
convmodel.summary()

#apply the segmentation to each layer
time_dist=TimeDistributed(convmodel)(reshaped)

from cgru import CGRU

up=CGRU(go_backwards=False, return_sequences=True, name="up")

up=up(time_dist)

output=Reshape([1,40,40,40])(up)

model=Model(input=inputs, output=output)
print(model.summary())
```

On a computer with Theano as the backend, this works.
The model summary is:

```
________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                     Output Shape          Param #     Connected to                     
====================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)             (None, 1, 40, 40, 40) 0                                            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
reshape_1 (Reshape)              (None, 40, 1, 40, 40) 0           input_1[0][0]                    
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
timedistributed_1 (TimeDistribute(None, 40, 3, 40, 40) 30          reshape_1[0][0]                  
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
up (CGRU)                        (None, 40, 1, 40, 40) 0           timedistributed_1[0][0]          
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
reshape_2 (Reshape)              (None, 1, 40, 40, 40) 0           up[0][0]                         
====================================================================================================
Total params: 30
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

But on a computer with tensorflow as the backend, the code fails.
I've added a `model.summary()` for the `convmodel`. Up to that it works:

```
Layer (type)                     Output Shape          Param #     Connected to                     
====================================================================================================
input_4 (InputLayer)             (None, 1, 40, 40)     0                                            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
convolution2d_2 (Convolution2D)  (None, 3, 40, 40)     30          input_4[0][0]                    
====================================================================================================
Total params: 30
```

But then the program crashes:

> ValueError: Shapes (?, ?, 40, 40) and (40, ?, 40) are not compatible

It seems like Theano and Tensorflow have different (and incompatible) placeholders for the batch_size ?
Please note that I configured Keras to use "th" image layout in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is solved.
The `initial_states` expect a list and the `output_dimension` had to be fixed.
Now it seems to work.
There are some other problems with the underlying backend (eg. Theano vs Tensorflow) but that seems to be offtopic for this question.

Once I'm sure that the problem has really been fixed and that the Layer is able to learn, I'll update this answer with all the necessary steps.